# Unable to get dialog box in svg using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, dialog, dynamic-html

i am trying to get a dialog box when I click a line in svg. For this I have to use vanilla javascript and it should be inside the  tag. I cannot use html. So, I am trying to use dynamic html in the javascript.
I have the following code to genertae the dialog box. Its working fine outside the svg but when I put it inside the svg I am getting " Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null" error.
Here is my code :

```
    function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("DIALOG");
    var t = document.createTextNode("This is an open dialog window");
    x.setAttribute("open", "open");
    x.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(x);
    }
```

and the error:
[image]

Can someone please help me with this error?

Comment: Script block is to be in CDATA block consider character data support in XML. Maybe this can be useful https://www.tutorialspoint.com/svg/svg_interactivity.htm. If not can you send more detail about the svg.

Comment: @ john.dacost Hi! Thank you for your comment. I looked at the link and kept CDATA block but still its not working. So, in the document the svg is inside the html. But in my case I cannot use html and have to get the dialog box when I open the svg image and click on the line.

Comment: <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 130.01 409.42" width="500" height="500">
    <title>fibula_500</title>
    <script>
        <![CDATA[
        function myFunction() {
        var x = document.createElement("DIALOG");
        var t = document.createTextNode("This is an open dialog window");
        x.setAttribute("open", "open");
        x.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(x);
        }
        ]]>
    </script>
    <line x1="52.76" y1="8.23" x2="52.76" y2="401.15""onclick="myFunction()"/></svg>

Comment: Please post the error as text, so that it appears when someone searches for it.

Answer (score 1):

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null` mean that the `body` element do not exist. If you want to append child select the svg tag like this -> `document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];` or add the `<body></body>` inside the svg.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function move()
        {
            var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0]; //add this line
            var x = document.createElement("DIALOG");
            var t = document.createTextNode("This is an open dialog window");
            x.setAttribute("open", "open");
            x.appendChild(t);
            svg.appendChild(x); //add this.line
        };
        </script>
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" onclick="move()" />
    </svg>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply and sorry for the late reply. I was still stuck into this.

Comment: Did my solution solve your problem ? if yes can you validate my answer as accepted. 

If not, can you provide the solution you used to solve your problem that might be of interest/help to other people.